# substitute the variable inside a string

Tags: ruby

I have a string like this

```
p="23232"
str="policy var=p saved" #It could be p or a or b, any variable.
```

I want to substitute the value of p in the place of var=p but I found a way to replace p in the place of var=p.

```
p="23232"
str="policy var=p saved"

p str.gsub(/var=(.)/,"\\1")
```

This code is replacing var=p with p but I want to substitute the value of p in the place of var=p like

output

```
policy 23232 saved
```

I know this can be accomplished by giving block to gsub but I don't know how.

Comment: Do like this ..  str.gsub("var=p", p)

Comment: I don't know whether it's p or a or b or z. That's why I am trying to write this code `p str.gsub(/var=(.)/,"\\1")`

Comment: Is `p` equal to `'a'`, `'b'` or `'z'` literally? If not, what might be its value? Any single lowercase letter? Any string?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Variable name is not only p,it could be a or anything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really have to, you can get to a local variable by name using `Binding#local_variable_get`:

```
p="23232"
str="policy var=p saved"

str.gsub(/var=(\w+)/) { binding.local_variable_get($1) }
```

However, I would strongly suggest that instead of a local variable, you use a hash:

```
vars = { "p" => "23232" }
str="policy var=p saved"

str.gsub(/var=(\w+)/) { vars[$1] }
```

EDIT: Local variables are very different from instance variables. There are multiple approaches possible.

Getting the instance variable directly is the worst one, as you may be skipping logic that would be implemented in an accessor. Note that instance variables' names start with `@`.

A better approach is to invoke the accessor, but this again will need `send`.

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar
  def initialize(bar)
    @bar = bar
  end
end

foo = Foo.new("baz")
str = "policy var=bar saved"

# by direct access
str.gsub(/var=(\w+)/) { foo.instance_variable_get("@" + $1) }
# by invoking the accessor
str.gsub(/var=(\w+)/) { foo.send($1) }
```

The best approach is, again, use a hash and index values by a key, not multiple instance variables. I am answering for educational purposes, but please, please, in real code, do this instead:

```
class Foo
  def initialize()
    @vars = { "bar" => "baz" }
  end

  def replace_by_hash(str)
    str.gsub(/var=(\w+)/) { @vars[$1] }
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
str = "policy var=bar saved"

foo.replace_by_hash(str)
```

Comment: Awesome Dude! Thanks a lot. but I don't know why you introduced `|m|` inside the block because you are not using the variable m.

Comment: Eh good point. Fingers on autopilot, no better reason. :P Removed now.

Comment: Hi, you used `binding.local_variable_get($1)` but actually I have to get it from instance variable. What modification should I do so that it would work? I tried with `binding.instance_variable_get($1) ` but it says `instance_variable_get': 'p' is not allowed as an instance variable name (NameError)`

Comment: `str.gsub(/var=(\w+)/) { instance_variable_get("@#{$1}") }`. There is zero sense to call `instance_variable_whatever` on `binding` because `binding` has no anything `instance`-like.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ I surely upvoted it because it solves the issue, but I have to notice this is **extremely** error-prone and should be avoided at any cost. The code relying on such tricks is unsupportable and in general _very_ low quality.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin `str.gsub(/var=(\w+)/) { instance_variable_get("@#{$1}") }` This perfectly solves my problem, thank you very much!

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: Absolutely agreed, I noted twice throughout the answer (and here for the third time) that this is not the way to do it in practice.

Comment: @Amadan Thanks for such a detailed answer. That explains me clearly! Thanks.

Comment: Btw, [`Object#instance_variable_get`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get) is public.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: Wow, I was sure it wasn't. Who knows why. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
p="23232"
str="policy var=p saved"

str.gsub(/var=(.)/) { instance_eval($1) }
  #=> "policy 23232 saved"
```

Comment: Oh, that's amazing too!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do it
`p="23232"
str="policy var=#{p} saved"
"policy var=23232 saved"`

Comment: You can't change the string!

Comment: How can you change the string?

Comment: Didn't get your question? 
Doing this will change the var str as well.